# onclick function for input checkbox - check on page load and also on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

```
$('input.ShowResellerAccounts').on('click', function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $('tbody#pages').hide();
    } else {
        $('tbody#pages').show();
    }
});
```

which hides/shows a table tbody id on click.

how can i make this code run on page load as well as on click?

Answer (score 2):

In the document.ready function you can trigger the click event like

```
$('input.ShowResellerAccounts').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

Separate it into a function and bind in on *load* as well as on *click*:

```
function checkInput(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $('tbody#pages').hide();
    } else {
        $('tbody#pages').show();
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input.ShowResellerAccounts')
      .on('click', checkInput) // bind to click
      .each(checkInput); // call now
});
```

Answer (score 0):

u can use $(document).ready :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//put your code here
});
```